# Connection String and Datacontext in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I am developing a site using ASP.NET, SQL 2008 and LINQ. I want to ask about the connection string. I have made a class like that to get the datacontext in each page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public static class DatabaseConnection
{
    static DataClassesDataContext datacontext;    
    public static DataClassesDataContext getConnection()
    {
       datacontext = new DataClassesDataContext(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname; Integrated Security=True");
        return datacontext;
    }
}
```

Is that a correct way to get the connection in each page?

Also about 'Data Source', when I deploy the site what will it be? And what is the difference between data source and address keywords?

Comment: In web application, you have to create & dispose data-context over a request - so I am not sure if using a singleton is an good approach. I would suggest using a factory method to create data context initialized with connection string from configuration. If you must hold the same context over a request then store it in HttpContext and write a wrapper property to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a valid way of getting the data context instance, yes.  You can use **Data Source** or **Server** I believe.

Please be aware that DataContext is IDisposable, so make sure it's not left hanging around after usage, I tend to do:

```
using (var context = DataHelper.GetContext())
{
   // Stuff.
}
```

Also, you should really put your connection strings in the configuration file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Live" connectionString="blah;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Much better if you place your Connection string on your Web.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Have a look at this:

[LINQ To SQL and the Web.Config ConnectionString Value](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/07/LINQ-To-SQL-and-the-WebConfig-ConnectionString-Value)

[LINQ to SQL Connection Strings with class library projects](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Connection-Strings-with-class-library-projects.aspx)

Regards